# Why has my bootstrap.css file stopped updating?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap in an ASP.NET MVC application.  I changed one single value in the `bootstrap.css` file and now it's not updating.  When I actually view the source file in debug mode, it also appears as though I have updated nothing.  I have had an issue before where it didn't update upon deployment, and in that case I had to delete the minified file, so I also tried deleting every bootstrap file (aside from the scripts) except bootstrap.css, but still it is as if I never updated it even in debug mode.  I used to be able to change the file and the screen would live update in debug mode.  It's like somehow I totally locked it but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the basics, have you definitely hit CTRL + F5 (as opposed to just F5) when viewing the page to ensure that you're not viewing a cached version of the page? I've had a similar issue where, even though changes to a stylesheet are usually picked up when a page is reloaded, sometimes you need to force the cache to refresh to view the page correctly.